# Apply `the_content' filter to theme customisation live preview

Tags: customization, filters, theme-customizer

I'm using `'transport' => 'postMessage'` to update the text within the footer area during theme customisation live preview.

My problem is that on my website, the corresponding theme setting (`footer_text`) has `the_content` filters applied to it. Is there any way to apply that filter via JS, or I am stuck with `'transport' => 'refresh'` for situations like this? Thanks.

```
(function($){

    /** Update the footer text */
    wp.customize('footer_text', function(value){
        value.bind(function(newval){
            $('#footer-left').html(newval);
        });
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: The point of postMessage is that it's sending data directly, in the browser. It's not going through the server, so no, you cannot apply PHP filters to it unless it's using refresh.

Comment: I've never looked in to this before today, I wasn't sure if an AJAX call was being made anywhere as part of the preview. Sad times :( I suppose I could make my own AJAX call, although that seems like overkill for this particular scenario! Thanks.

Comment: @Otto as an answer please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've again been looking in to this so I've decided to post an answer because I actually have done this using an AJAX call.

As pointed out in the comments to my question by [@Otto](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/2232/otto) -

> The point of postMessage is that it's sending data directly, in the browser. It's not going through the server, so no, you cannot apply PHP filters to it unless it's using refresh."

So using the original example from above for context, you could apply filters to text updated via the `postMessage` method using an AJAX call as follows -

JS in your **theme-customiser.js** file -

```
(function($){

    /** Update the footer text */
    wp.customize('footer_text', function(value){
        value.bind(function(newval){

            var data = {
                action: 'filter_using_the_content',
                text:   newval
            }

            $.post(MyAjax.ajaxurl, data, function(response){
                $('#footer-left').html(response);
            });

        });
    });

})(jQuery);
```

PHP in your **functions.php** file -

```
add_action('wp_ajax_filter_using_the_content', 'my_filter_using_the_content');
function my_filter_using_the_content(){

    echo apply_filters('the_content', $_POST['text']);
    die();  // Required for a proper result

}
```